# How to move lines containing specific text to top of file in same order as code executed?

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, sed, ed

How to move lines containing specific text to top of file in same order as code executed?

Here is the code I have:

```
printf 'g?_001\|_002\|_003\|_004\|_005?m0\nwq\n' | ed -s target_file
```

> ( credit goes to **steeldriver** for helping me get this far. Truely an amazing user of this site! )

This moves them to the top like so:

```
name_003
name_005
name_004
name_002
name_001
```

*or however order they were in originally, just to the top.*

but I need them to be put in the same order as I have them in within the `printf` and ed `code`, so in this case, like:

```
name_001
name_002
name_003
name_004
name_005
```

Anyone familiar with `printf` and `ed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use separate move commands:

```
ex -sc 'g?_005?m0' -c 'g?_004?m0' -c 'g?_003?m0' -c 'g?_002?m0' -c 'g?_001?m0' -c wq target_file
```

Note that:

- I'm using `ex` (actually, Vim) here, not `ed`. You can specify the ex-commands in the command line using the `-c` option, so `printf` isn't needed.
- The patterns must be in reverse order (`005` gets moved to the top first, then `004`, pushing down `005`, then `003`, pushing down both `004` and `005`, ...)

With `printf` and `ed`, maybe:

```
(printf 'g?%s?m0\n' {005..001}; printf 'wq\n') |
  ed -s target_file
```

Comment: The `ex` command does not work for me :/ it simply doesn't have any effect when used. I am running Arch Linux Manjaro.

Comment: Works fine enough for me. What was the actual command you used, and the actual input you provided?

Comment: With Arch Linux, `ed` is GNU ed, but `ex` is probably [heirloom vi](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/vi.html). Try installing Vim and using it instead.

Comment: It's saying `'-sc' is not a valid file`

Comment: When I use `vim` rather than `ex`. It says `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Mar 29 2019 20:08:59)
Garbage after option argument: "-sc"
More info with: "vim -h"
`

Comment: When using `vi` rather than `ex` it says `[Using open mode]` and does nothing as well... :/ ?

Comment: You're not copying these commands to Word or something, are you? I cannot reproduce your errors, in particular `ex` *does not* complain that `-sc` isn't a valid file. Please provide the actual commands you have used. Edit your question to add more information.

Comment: However your printf is working, but how would I do numbers: 003, 007, 022 ? In that exact order ?

Comment: Lmao! No, right in my console... hahahah :D

Comment: Just the same ones you provided in answer, only thing I changed was `target_file` to `list.txt`, literally thats it.

Comment: `(printf 'g?%s?m0\n' 003 007 022; printf ...`

Comment: And how would I do it without the ( ) around printf?

Comment: Why would you want to do it without the `()` around `printf`?

Comment: Because I need to tie this into another list of... oh nevermind its working with everything else. Sorry about that. Hey man, thank you!!